# Virtual table 

Tags: sql

```
CREATE TABLE #Report(
Cell int,
CellValue double)
```

Error here

```
DECLARE @Report TABLE (
Cell int,
CellValue double)
```

And here

So ... how to work with virtual table :S and why error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
DECLARE @Report TABLE ( 
Cell int, 
CellValue float)
```

Have a look at [Data Types (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752.aspx)

You can try [float, real](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173773.aspx) or [decimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx)